# Adding footer to eBay store category/search/custom pages

Tags: html, css, ebay-api

I have added a custom header to my store using the theme display settings, and a custom footer by setting a custom page as the store homepage.
It all works well upto here, but when i move to the category or search pages, only the header is applied to all the pages but the footer goes missing.
Can someone point out how this can be done? I know its possible as i have seen other stores (like [this one](http://stores.ebay.com/Official-Sony-Store)) where it is done.
There are [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808192/ebay-store-design-custom-html-to-apply-to-all-category-pages-like-the-home-page) posts here which mention that we can do stuff by adding html/css to the header. But this wont work for adding a footer.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var con = getElementsByClass('pagecontainer');

var mvobj = document.getElementById('footer'); //footer can be defined as promotion box

var obj = getElementsByClass('stBadge');

con[0].insertBefore(mvobj,obj[0]);
```

Comment: But still this donot show footer designed as ebay promotion box named as footer.
Can anyone help?

Comment: To put background image to footer, add following in css:

`.whiter-w {

  background: url(bg.png) no-repeat;

  height: 142px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

adding a footer that will appear on all pages on ebay store is achieved via store.js..

[Video explaining editing ebay store footer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m_jWPyRKnCg)